# anArray[0] returns undefined even when there is an element inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I've typed the following code
​
​ `console.log(balanrrey); console.log(balanrrey[0]); ​`

then this shows on the console:

Array [] 
0: 10
​1: 40.28
​2: 20.14
​3: 24.34
​length: 4

**undefined**

Any idea on why this might be happening? I swear I spent 2 hours trying to find an answer.

Comment: Is the array being filled in by asynchronous code?

Comment: are you sure the key is `0` and not something else? e.g. associative arrays

Comment: Notice that the console.log shows `[]`. At the time you logged it, the array was empty. It was filled in asynchronously, so when you expanded it you saw the contents added later.

Comment: Give more code and information about your problem. Are you typing the code in the console? Where are you adding values / creating `balanrrey`?